# Android(<=2.2) Large File Downloads using android market apk expansion downloader library

Tags: android, download, android-2.2-froyo

Has anyone tried using market apk expansion downloader library (available as an add-on) for downloading large files on android <= 2.2? The source code is a bit difficult to understand and I was not able to figure out how it can be used for downloading any large files in general. Are there any alternatives for downloading large files on lower android devices(apart from writing my own DownloadService which I wouldn't prefer doing if there is something already available).

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to use it but the docs do state the the expansion downloader library is compatibile with API Level 4, taken from the docs:

> Note: By default, the Downloader Library requires API level 4, but the
>   APK Expansion Zip Library requires API level 5.

I completely agree that the source code is difficult to follow, however it was designed in such a way to be fault tolerant to network issues.

I think you can take the sample and roll with that, however I found it was very difficult to test.

We ended up going with our own in the end (using an Arbitrary server) to host the downloads.

I do not believe there are any alternatives, however the downloader library does have a few gems. For instance the Expansion Zip Library can be used independently of the Downloader Library and is a great way to read content directly from the zip.

The only challenge would be writing your own downloader service and performing a CRC check.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like API 4 or >

The expansion API is used for "permanent" file extensions to your application, they don't want you to move them or delete them or even unpack them etc. but use them in place, it's unclear what would happen if you did but I suspect a lot of odd side effects.

You also don't have direct control of when this file is downloaded, it has to be associated in the market and then it happens automatically unless for some reason it "fails" in which case when your app starts you are expect to initiate the process manually and then you need to use the Download Libary, else it's automagic as my 3 year old says.

From your post you may be looking for a way to get large files (more than one) and do what you want with them, if so this is not a good method to do that since every time you add a new file via the market it would tell your users you have an updated version and overwrite the older file (though you can use the patch extension to avoid that if you are updating the original but that only moves it back one step)

All of that is here [what expansions files are for and how to use them](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html#Downloading)

If you just want a method to get large files using your own server take a look at the support package and specifically the loader and loader manager.  They also say they are making source code to the extension library downloader and zip file manager available but I haven't bothered to check that yet.